# Javascript - find all classes from array, grab and return inner text from classes

Tags: javascript, for-loop, innerhtml

I have an array of class names that I want to search a page for. Then I'd like to find all those elements, grab the text inside, and append it to a div.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = 'List of names from this page';
document.body.appendChild(div); 

var classNameArray = ['user', 'username', 'fullname', 'profile-field', 'author', 'screen-name'];

for (var i = 0; i < classNameArray.length; i++) {

  element = classNameArray[i];
  getSuggestedAuthors(element);

  function getSuggestedAuthors(element) {
    var classes = document.getElementsByClassName(element);
    var index;
    for (var index = 0; index < classes.length; index++) {
      var class = classes[index];
      var textInsideClass = class.innerHTML;
      div.appendChild(textInsideClass);
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this, it gives me:

```
Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.
```

I believe the problem is occuring at `var textInsideClass = class.innerHTML`, because when I remove that, it simply grabs all the classes and appends them to the div. However, I'd like to only get the text inside the class.

Anyone know how to do this **without jQuery**? I'm injected this hs through Google Chrome's [executeScript injection](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript).

Thanks so much!

Comment: Variable names like `a,b,c,d,e,f,g` don't really help to understand your code...

Comment: Yes, but they will help you win an obfuscated code contest.

Comment: Really? I find it easier for me to understand my code that way, but I will rename for clarity's sake :p

Comment: "I find it easier for me to understand my code "  The goal is to have other people understand your code.

Comment: Also it seems like some variables are not defined with `var`. Are they defined on another scope? Dunno looks a bit confusing

Comment: `appendChild` only works with nodes. You can create a new text node with `document.createTextNode` and append it. Also, you can use `textContent` if you want the text, instead of `innerHTML` that gives you everything, including tags. (textContent was finally added in IE9, supported in all other browsers since forever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to support chrome then all of the handy methods on the Array.prototype should exist :)

```
var a = document.createElement('div');
a.innerHTML = 'List of names from this page';
document.body.appendChild(a); 

function getSuggestedAuthors(elements) {
  for (var d = 0; d < elements.length; d++) {
    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(elements[d].innerText));//append loop items text to a
  }
}
['user', 'username', 'fullname', 'profile-field', 'author', 'screen-name'].map(function(cls) {
  return document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
}).forEach(getSuggestedAuthors);
```

Comment: If you use `forEach` and `map` you might as well just use `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(classes), fn)`

Comment: Ahh, my bad - this is for a Chrome extension injection, so forEach wouldn't work either. I started off by trying to do that, but the console was giving me something like "no method forEach"

Comment: @Michelle for each is supported in all versions of chrome afaik so it should be fine for extension injections http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.forEach

Answer (score 3):

I think your issue is that appendChild only works with nodes. You might be better off just appending to innerHTML using something along the lines of `a.innerHTML += f.innerHTML`.

You should also be sure to move the getSuggestedAuthors function out of the loop. It works ok as it is, but it's much better form not to declare functions inside a loop.

Comment: You're right! It works beautifully, thank you... And yes, I really should.